# How to host two react app on same document

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

i want to have two react app one for admin and other for public.admin should get access to public app.and i have no idea how to implement it.i tried various method including creating two react app separately for admin and public.but was not able to get it done